# Django unable to save a text value in DB

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm reading an e-mail content through IMAP in my Django app.

When I try to assign some of the parsed content to the object and do .save() it returns:

```
ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

When I print the variable type: . Field in the DB is defined as CharField. I tried TextField as well, but the result is the same.

How I can solve that?

Answer (score 0):

if your mail text is in mail_text, do this:

```
mail_text = unicode(mail_text)
```